# CakePHP How to get Photo from different table?

Tags: cakephp

Hi i have two table `friends` and `galleries` I want to use CakePHP model Association between two table which `Friend.friend_id = 1` and `Gallery.user_id = 1`

**friends**

```
id    friend_id
-------------
1        5
2        1
3        6
```

**galleries**

```
id   user_id    photo
------------------------
1      1      photo1.jpg
2      6      photo2.jpg
3      5      photo3.jpg
```

Above two table i want to join. But i am unable to join. Please help me.

Comment: Do you need just the SQL query ?

Comment: No i want to model association in CakePHP

Comment: read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html for basics,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research finally i got my answer. This code helps to other-

```
   //$user_id=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
   $user_id=1;
   $this->Friend->bindModel(
                array('hasOne' => array(
                        'Gallery' => array(
                            'className' => 'Gallery',
                            'foreignKey' => FALSE,
                            'conditions' => array('Friend.friend_id=Gallery.user_id'),                                
                            'type' => 'LEFT'
                        )
                    )
                )
       );

    $this->Friend->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'friend_id', 'conditions'=>array('Friend.user_id'=>$user_id)))));

   $data = $this->Friend->find('all');
   pr($data);
```